# Skip reading xml elements that are inside a certain parent node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, kml

I am reading xml gps data using xmlreader.read(). I want to output all coordinate points that are not located within a line element. Below is contained within the file, and I want to exclude the coordinates listed.

```
<place>
  <desc>home</desc>
  <line>
      <coordinate>123,123,123</coordinate>
      <coordinate>1223,1223,22123</coordinate>
  </line>
</place>
```

This is an example of a valid coordinate, that I want to output and process (all located within the same file):

```
<place>
   <desc>home</desc>
   <point>
      <coordinate>123,123,123</coordinate>
   </point>
</place>
```

The difference is that one is part of a line object, and the other is a point. I currently have this code, and its grabbing everything.

```
            while (lxmlReader.Read())
            {

                    if (lxmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (lxmlReader.Name == "coordinate")
                        {
                            rtxtOutput.Text += "\r\nElement Name: " + lxmlReader.Name.ToString();
                            rtxtOutput.Text += " Value: " + lxmlReader.ReadInnerXml().ToString();
                        }
                    }                   
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure how to do it (or if it is possible) using XmlReader - Have you considered loading the XML into an XmlDocument or XDocument object which will allow you to perform proper queries on it.

You could then do something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("path.xml");
foreach (XmlElement  pointCoord in doc.SelectNodes("/place/point/coordinate"))
{
    /Do something
}
```

You will find lots of samples of selecting nodes based on parents etc using XPath online.

Comment: Thank you, this managed to solve the issue. I may need to checkout this LINQ method because I have another case to solve that requires certain sibling element conditions to be met.

Comment: Linq is just as good (actually probably better). You can use it in the way that @itsme86 describes, or using doc.XPathSelectElements("xpath").

Comment: You can perfectly well evaluate sibling conditions in an XPath query, either using the preceding-sibling or following-sibling axes, or by using the parent axis and working back down. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ for details.

Comment: I think you can also solve this with your original approach, i.e. using  XMLReader.Read(), but you would have to track the state yourself as you navigate the nodes. Having said that, I'd stick with Chris's simpler approach unless you are dealing documents that are so large that you don't want them all in memory at once (the definition of large here probably depends on whether this is single-user or a server with lots of clients)

Answer (score 1):

If you have LINQ available, I'd do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> coords = XElement.Load("gps.xml")
    .Descendants("point")
    .Descendants("coordinate")
    .Select(c => c.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will defiantly need to checkout what LINQ is all about.